# How Can I Mask a UIView and Not just the UIImage

Tags: ios, objective-c, masking, uiblureffect

I am trying to mask a complete UIView is this possible? The view I am trying to mask has a blur effect layered on top of it. I am to successfully mask the image under the UIView but not the entire View itself. Basically I need to be able to mask a UIView.

Comment: add some code & screenshot

Comment: Mask it with what!?  What is what you so-call view if it's not UIView?

Comment: masking uiview with doublemask opertation and inserting uimageview:  https://gist.github.com/anonymous/a76ab76ff5fa77d3724f

Comment: Let me be more clear, I am trying to create a UIImage that is masked with a UIBlurEffect on that Image however the UIBlurEffect is covering the entire view. I would like for the blur to be strictly on the image itself

Comment: Let me be more clear, I am trying to create a UIImage that is masked with a UIBlurEffect on that Image however the UIBlurEffect is covering the entire view. I would like for the blur to be strictly on the image itself and not the cover the entire view. Do you have an email address in which I can share my source code with you via GitHub @Larcerax